# Canon EOS 50D can't save pictures anymore

Tags: canon, canon-50d

The other day I wanted to take a picture with my 50D. I turned it on, aimed and when I wanted to take the picture my camera froze when saving the picture. The red light was still lit but I could not do anything anymore. Even turning the camera off did not work (it did not turn off). So I removed the battery and re-inserted it.

Then I tried the Live-View mode and everytime the image starts to appear on the LCD screen the 50D freezes. Does anyone know what this might be?

Answer (score 8):

If the firmware of your camera is older than version 1.0.3 you need to update the firmware.

50D camera's with firmware before 1.0.3 sometimes had the [issue](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0810/08102802canon50dfirmware.asp) you described.

Get the latest firmware (1.0.7) [here](http://web.canon.jp/imaging/eosd/firm-e/eos50d/firmware.html). Installation instructions are provided.

Answer (score 5):

There could be a variety of reasons:

1. Have you tried a different CF card? Perhaps the CF card you are using has gone south. This is probably the best case scenario, because it's a $30 fix.
2. Have you tried shooting tethered mode without a CF card? If you can save images directly to your computer, then it's likely that CF-card slot is busted.
3. Have you tried updating your camera's firmware? Perhaps this is a known issue with the older firmwares.
4. Have you tried a different lens with your body? It's highly unlikely that it's your lens causes the problem, but I have had lenses cause weird issues with my canon bodies before.

If trying a new CF, a different lens, or updating firmware don't resolve the issue, you'll need to send it in to Canon for repair.

Comment: 1.: Yes, tried. Didn't work.
2.: Yes, I have the eos-record app for the computer. When recording a movie the camera froze, too.
3.: I'm going to try that. But still seems weird that the camera stops working all the sudden.
4.: Yes, tried two different lenses.

If nothing works I will have to send it in for repair. Or since my warranty is still valid for replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something to do with your CF card or the lens, try a different CF card.

Is the camera throwing any errors?

I had something similar to this and it was due to the lens (70-200mm L) needing to clear all all memory and power from the capacitors. I let the lens sit detached from the body for a few days and all is well now.